# Windows 7 Professional N needs to be just Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7

I have a laptop at work that originally had Windows 7 Home Premium on it.  We have a tech that comes in a few times a week to do some of our support work, and we asked him to upgrade the laptop to Windows 7 Professional.

Before he left he told us the upgrade didn't work and that we'd have to order a disk.  Upon checking the computer it seemed he had upgraded to Windows Professional 7 N.
It had *not* previously been Home Premium N, so I'm not exactly sure how he managed to upgrade it to an N edition.

I do not understand why he didn't run the Any Time Upgrade, but that is now irrelevant.

How can I change Professional N to regular Professional?  I would like to avoid having to restore it back to Home if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, The [N-Editions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Standard_editions) are exactly the same as the standard editions, except they are lacking Windows Media Player.  You should be able to [download](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/default.mspx) and install Windows Media Player and essentially have a full Professional version of Windows 7.  Windows will still report itself as Windows 7 Professional N, but you will have all of the same features as Windows 7 Professional.

Further information on what was removed from Windows XP when the original N editions were released can be found at:

- [Description of Windows XP Home Edition N and Windows XP Professional N](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886540)
- [Microsoft Implementation of European Commission Decision](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/Antitrust/EUDecision/FAQ.aspx)

Comment: Strange than on MSDN, the N editions ISOs are about 300MB smaller than the others.  Is windows media player really so big?

Comment: and are lacking internet explorer

Comment: It's only the KN editions that are lacking internet explorer.